# How to select a div with specific css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
//style
.TemplateBox1{display:none;} 

//Html
<div class="TemplateBox1" id="9">  1 </div>
<div class="TemplateBox1" id="10"> 2 </div>
<div class="TemplateBox1" id="11"> 3 </div>

//jQuery
$('div', this).each(function (e) { //Do something  });
```

This is a part from my code, at start the divs display (CSSproperty) is none (not shown) and after the user click on a certain button the property of the div changed to block (shown). I need to select only the divs that their property is display:block using jQuery, I tried :

```
$('div', this).**css("display")=="block"**.each(function (e) { //Do something  }); - didn't work..
```

What do I need to add to my jQuery...

Comment: `$('div:visible', this).each(function (e) {  });`

Comment: Note that in HTML4, IDs should begin with a letter. HTML5 is more permissive, but CSS won't target an ID that begins with a number.

Comment: Thank you, I am using HTML5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector,

```
$('div:visible')
```

It seems that you are using `TemplateBox1` class to hide those elements, so you can write in this manner too, that is by using [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
$('div:not(.TemplateBox1)')
```

Comment: Thank you, will accept it as an answer in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this : `:visible` selector for div

```
$(this).find('div:visible').each(function(){
 // do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is `$('div:visible')`

another way is ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ae46G/))

```
$('.TemplateBox1', this).each(function (e) {
    var $css = $(this).css('display');
    if($css == 'none'){
        $(this).css('display','block')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use pure JS ?

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
foreach(var i = 0;i < list.length, i++)
{ 
   if(list[i].style.display == "block")
    {
      // do Something;
    }
}
```